# Debian / Postfix / Header Checks / Changing Subject based on "To:"

Tags: linux, postfix

I'm trying to configure a change of subject for incoming emails based on the "To:" address of the (virtual) email address, rather unsuccessfully. I run into two problems.

The **first problem** is that I can't seem to find a proper way to change the subject line based on the "To:" address. I have:

In main.cf:

```
header_checks= pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

and in header_checks:

```
if /^To: test@example\.com/
/^Subject: (.+)$/ REPLACE Subject: [TEST] $1
endif
```

pcre is installed, but the rule doesn't seem to be applied. I tried testing it with

```
postmap -q "To: test@example.com" pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

and there is no output of that command. I am unsure whether this means that the rule did not apply or whether it doesn't show anything due to the application of a rule regarding the subject although the test is on the to header.

The **second problem** is that when I replace the entire file header_checks by this:

```
/^To: test@example\.com/ REJECT
```

...I can successfully test it with postmap -q (yield REJECT), but incoming mail isn't actually rejected. So I'm guessing this is another issue in addition to the one above.

Thanks.